# Excel - Find the matching values between two columns return adjacent value into a new column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have tried looking for this answer, but with no joy.

I have two columns with IDs Columns A and B, and in Column C are the Count totals of Column B. What I need to do is find the match of Column B to Column A, then return in Column D the values of C, but in line with the row of Column A.

May be easier to show a picture:

[image]

Any help would be amazing! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Q: is it a typo in the 3rd row from the bottom? 451 instead of 596?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to `XLOOKUP` the respective row value of column A with column B to return the related value from column C

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929

If you encounter some issues/not expected result with your line of code, you may want to post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction the XLOOKUP was perfect for what I was doing. Here is the formula used and the result if anyone might have the same challenge:

The formula:

> =XLOOKUP($A2,$B$2:$B$9,$C$2:C9)

The result:

[image]